# DevExpress MVC ASPxImageSlider - Endless Paging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I'm trying to replace a jquery carousel plugin with the DevExpress ImageSlider MVC extension, utilizing the Navigation Bar-style layout and a custom thumbnail template.  It's all working very nicely, except that the end-users prefer an endless paging experience, meaning that once you've reached the end of the list of items in one direction, it starts over from the beginning of the list.  It doesn't seem this is supported in the DevExpress ImageSlider, but wanted to reach out just in case someone had found a solution.  Is there a way to detect when you've reached the end of the list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, ASPxImageSlider does not provide such functionality out-of-the-box. DevExpress consider possibility of implementing this functionality in the future.

Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?